# Is there a way to write a program which keeps using more and more memory? I want to write a simple C program for that

Tags: c, linux, memory-management

I used the following code but the VIRT column in top command shows constant memory allocated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int main (int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    while(1)
    {
        int *pointer;
         pointer = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
         *(pointer+3) = 99;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Try `while(fork())`...

Comment: If I replace `stdio` by `stdlib`, I can compile your code and when running, it consumes more and more memory.

Comment: The compiler may optimize away your entire program when it sees it does not do anything as defined by the C standard. Try changing `int *pointer;` to `volatile int *pointer;`. This tells the compiler it must do the assignments to `*(pointer+3)`; they cannot be optimized away.

Comment: @choroba yes it worked but my VM got stuck. Btw any idea why changing stdio to stdlib does this? I thought stdlib is included even if we don't mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Initialize the memory.

Use `memset` to initialize the memory:

```
memset(pointer, 0, the_size);
```

Also you could use `calloc` that not only allocates memory but also fills it with zeros for you:

```
pointer = calloc(10, sizeof(int));
```

[about calloc:](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_calloc.htm)
The C library function void *calloc(size_t nitems, size_t size) allocates the requested memory and returns a pointer to it. The difference in malloc and calloc is that malloc does not set the memory to zero where as calloc sets allocated memory to zero.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it works. The problem is my VM crashes within seconds so I cant monitor it. Is there any way to increase memory allocation slowly?

Comment: you can do some sleep in your loop